# grant select any table from one specific schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have just created a new read only user (TEMPDBREAD) for our developers @ our oracle Database 11.2.0.4

Now they like read access to all tables from just one schema (TEMPDBUSER)
is there an alternative to grant select any table. 
They should not be able to read the other schemes. But since the table structure often changes, it is difficult to justify everything manually.

That's why select any table is awarded very quickly and easier to place
Can i deny the access to the other schemes anyway?

Any Idea how i can solve this very simple?

BR Julian

Grant Table Access manually 
Grant Select ANY Table

Comment: There is some debate on the value of this. You can [vote here](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2333).

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  You either give them `select any table` and let them read any table in the database or you give them access to each table in `TempDBUser` individually.  In the vast, vast majority of cases, you'd want to give them access to each table in `TempDBUser` (presumably via a role because there will be many developer accounts that need to run queries).

It isn't clear to me why giving object-level access is problematic for you.  "Table structure changes" do not require new grants since they're just changes to existing objects.  If you really mean that new tables are created frequently, you'd just want to incorporate the grants into your change control and deployment process.

If you have a packaged application that creates new tables periodically (a terrible practice), you could create a DDL trigger that issued the grant every time a new table was created in `TempDBUser`.  You'd need a DDL trigger that submitted a job via the `dbms_job` package that did the actual grant which is a rather convoluted architecture but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    spool /tmp/grant_issue.sql
    select 'grant select on TEMPDBUSER.' || table_name || ' TO TEMPDBREAD;' from dba_tables  where owner='TEMPDBUSER' ;
    spool off;

    run the spool file.

    sqlplus @/tmp/grant_issue.sql
```